# Adjust Table Footer Height

Tags: html, css

I am having a difficult time adjusting the height of the table footer (tfoot).

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Poppins;
  src: url(./fonts/poppin/Poppins-Light.otf);
}
body{
  font-family: Poppins,arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.dataview{
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.dataview thead{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.dataview thead tr{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.dataview tbody tr:nth-last-child(1){
  border-bottom: none;
}
.dataview tbody{
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.dataview th, .dataview td{
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
.dataview th{
  height: 30px;
}
.dataview tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black
}
.dataview th.right, .dataview td.right{
  text-align:right;
}
.dataview th.center, .dataview td.center{
  text-align:center;
}
.dataview tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #ccd8ff;
}
.dataview tbody tr:hover td{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.dataview tfoot td{  
  height: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
/* clidata-browse */
.dataview#clidata-browse{
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dataview#clidata-browse td{
  height: 45px;
}
.dataview#clidata-browse th:nth-child(1),
.dataview#clidata-browse td:nth-child(1){
  min-width: 350px;
}
.dataview#clidata-browse th:nth-child(2),
.dataview#clidata-browse td:nth-child(2){
  min-width: 350px;
}
.dataview#clidata-browse th:nth-child(3),
.dataview#clidata-browse td:nth-child(3){
  min-width: 100px;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.dataview#clidata-browse tbody{
  height: 380px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Arrowleaf Sandbox</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table class="dataview" id="clidata-browse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th class="right">Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br>
        Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br>
        Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>This is a test</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

Attempted to adjust the height of the tfoot tag in the css (included in the fiddle).  I can increase the row height without issue but if I want the tfoot less than the size of the tbody rows it will not go smaller.  Any help is appreciated.

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spsimmons_64/yxfo6Lq1/)

Comment: use max-height instead height, scroll will happen once max height is reached https://jsfiddle.net/5naxopjd/

Comment: @SunnyPatel I posed the question an hour ago, what's the hurry for me selecting an answer?

Comment: @SunnyPatel, you did!  Tremendously!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Root Cause

It's pretty simple, and has to do with 2 competing CSS selectors for the `<tfoot/>`:

```
.dataview tfoot td{  
  height: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

And

```
.dataview#clidata-browse td{
  height: 45px;
}
```

I figured this out by inspecting the `tfoot td` tag:
[image]

### Explanation

The latter has a higher [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) because it contains the ID Selector `#clidata-browse`.

### Solution

To resolve this, you can do a couple of things, the easiest is to add the `!important` tag to `.dataview tfoot td` height CSS selector.

```
.dataview tfoot td {
  height: 20px !important;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can adjust the second selector to be the following:

```
.dataview#clidata-browse thead td,
.dataview#clidata-browse tbody td {
  height: 45px;
}
```

which avoids selecting the footer `<td/>` elements for a change in height.

Comment: The important flag is useful, but can make css much more complex to reason about later (especially in large projects or when there are multiple editors). I suggest avoiding it and instead modifying your css so it cascades appropriately. see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules. Instead of using !important, consider adding another rule: `.dataview#clidata-browse tfoot td{height: 20px}` or modifying your existing rule `.dataview tfoot td, .dataview#clidata-browse tfoot td{height: 20px}`

Comment: @Tai, That is an important (haha) rule of thumb to go on. However, with the context of ensuring the height for his table footers are separated, this use-case makes it appropriate. There's other solutions, such as adding an id to his `tfoot` selector (not scalable), or adding the height to the inline style (also not scalable), or even adjusting his second selector to specify `tbody` children only `.dataview#clidata-browse tbody td` (alternate solution, and scalable).

Comment: I elected to add the second selector rather than place the !important flag.  I don't like using them either.

Answer (score 0):

The `tfoot tag` is supporting `styles atributes` which you can use to improve height of it.
For example `<tfoot styles="height:500px"`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `display:block` to get your body scrolling, then you may also use `flex` and `grid` to reset the entire layout. Height can be then set on table itself.

example with scroll needed and not *(border added to show where cells stand)*:

```css
table {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}

thead {
  background: turquoise;
  padding-right: 1.1em;
}

thead tr,
tbody tr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 0.5fr;/* set column width here via fr, fit-content(),minmax(),px ,% or any value you that fits your needs best */
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0.25em;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

tfoot {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

tfoot tr {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 3px;
  border: solid 1px;
  display: flex;
}

tfoot tr td {
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="dataview" id="clidata-browse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th class="right">Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="30">This is a test</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<hr>
<table class="dataview" id="clidata-browse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th class="right">Balance</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 1<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust1@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$3000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Customer 2<br> Customer Address
      </td>
      <td>testcust2@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="right">$40.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="30">This is a test</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```